# projection onto affine image set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A={$y: y=Ax+b,A\in R^{n\times m}, x\in R^m$}
I want to compute the projection onto A from a point z$\in R^n$,is there a close formulation to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "closed form" solution is available, but I do not know how helpful it is (it requires solving a linear system of equations).

The projection problem is
$$
\min_{x, y} \quad \frac{1}{2}\|y - z\|^2 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad y = A x + b
$$
Substituting $y$ into the objective function, we obtain the *unconstrained* linear least-squares problem 
$$
\min_{x} \|A x + (b - z)\|^2 
$$
Least squares problems have a closed form solution which you can find in any text-book, or in Wikipedia. after finding the optimal $x^*$, your projection is $y^* = A x^* + b$. Have fun.

Comment: I assumed the asker wanted the Euclidean projection.

Comment: I understand now that the formulation of the asker is ambiguous : "projection from" maybe means for the asker "projection of" (it is your interpretation)